# Can a Kenyan person with a Schengen visa travel to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, kenyan-citizens

Can a Kenyan citizen who holds a Schengen visa travel to the UK for a short period?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The United Kingdom is not part of the Schengen area; so the Schengen visa is not valid for the UK.

Therefore, you would need a separate visa for the UK.

If you are ever in doubt as to the visa requirements for the UK, use the [check visa service at gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/kenya/tourism).